# can we create arrayfield without creating model container?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

I am facing problem in creating array field in mongo using django... I am using djongo connector... can't we create ArrayField in without specifying the model container ...

I don't want to specify model_container in ArrayField because I don't want to make my model a child class and don't want to give value each and every field for parent class assigned in model_container...

I tried -
from djongo import models
models.ArrayField()

I am expecting -
I just want to create array field in mongo db with json format/dictionary inside like
[{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.